# (Rails) How to get 'id' out of edit url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, url-routing

I have a model called `studies`.

After action redirect `redirect_to edit_study_path(@new_study)`,

URL: `http://localhost:3000/studies/2/edit`.

Is there anyway to customize an url after passing `id` ?

For example, `http://localhost:3000/study` 
(still going to the edit path, and still with the `:id` in the params)

Comment: I do not think so, without passing any params.

Comment: Can I get any feedback on the negative votes? How could I improve my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want is to edit the current study?

In this case, it's possible, using `ressource` instead of `ressources` in the routes.

Let's have an example:

```
  #in routes.rb
  resources :studies
  resource :study
```

Both of them will by default link to the StudiesController and call the same actions (eg. edit in your case) but in two different routes

```
  get "/studies/:id/edit" => "studies#edit"
  get "/study/edit" => "studies#edit"
```

in your edit action, you should then setup to handle correctly the parameters:

```
  def edit
     @study = params[:id].nil? ? current_study : Study.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Note you need a current_study method somewhere, and store the current_study in cookies/sessions to make it works.

Example:

```
# In application_controller.rb
def current_study
   @current_study ||= Study.find_by(id: session[:current_study_id]) #using find_by doesn't raise exception if doesn't exists
end

def current_study= x
   @current_study = x
   session[:current_study_id] = x.id
end

#... And back to study controller
def create
   #...
   #Eg. setup current_study and go to edit after creation
   if study.save
      self.current_study = study
      redirect_to study_edit_path #easy peesy
   end
end
```

Happy coding,

Yacine.

Comment: Why do you still check for params? What would put the id in params?

Comment: It's in the case you want to have two routes to the edit action: `/studies/:id/edit` and `/study/edit`. If you have only the route without params, so ignore the check and go straight to "current_study" ;-)